# c# mysql statement string

Tags: c#, mysql, string-literals

I'm looking for the most efficient way to handle a mysql string statement in c#.
The following psuedocode example shows a @ string literal where I have 2 variables inside the string that need to be substituted in with the variable contents.
Is there an efficient and simple way in c# to do this?

```
string region = "northwest";
string market = "Canada";

string stm = @"
    select distinct(position)
      from plan 
     where region = 'region'
       and market = 'market'
";
```

Comment: What are you using to connect to MySql and run the query? Ado.Net with the MySQL connector? MyODBC? MyOLEDB? You'll want to use a parameterized query, but just how you do that depends on what library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parameters like:

```
string stm = @"
    select distinct(position)
      from plan 
     where region = @region
       and market = @market
";


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(stm);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region",regionvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@market",marketvalue);
```

Comment: thanks... interesting that you don't need quotes around the variable .. where region = '@region'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.

Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class to *inject* a 'region' and 'market' values into the final `SQL string`

For complete example on `INSERT` statement have look on

**EDIT**

As correctly mantioned *dash* the valid class for accessing `MySQL` *could be* `MySqlParameter`.

[C# – Sql Parameters Source Code – Insert Statement](http://idealprogrammer.com/net-languages/code-samples/sql-parameters-insert-statement/)

Comment: MySqlParameter in this instance... :-)